# Angular Material UI Tooltip showing behind div

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I am building a todo application with Angular2 and AngularFire2 with Material UI styling. On part of the application, the material tooltips are showing up behind a div.

```html
<div class="view">
  <input class="toggle" type="checkbox" (click)="toggleTodoComplete(todo)" [checked]="todo.completed">
  <input type="text" class="todoEditable" [class.important]="todo.important"
         (keyup.enter)="updateTitle(todo, $event)" value="{{todo.title}}">
  <div class="todoActions">
    <img class="todoAction tooltip" md-tooltip="Alert" tooltip-position="below"
         src="../../assets/img/add_alert.svg"
         (click)="toggleModal(todo, 'addAlertModal')"/>
    <img class="todoAction tooltip" md-tooltip="Photo" tooltip-position="below"
         src="../../assets/img/insert_photo.svg"
         (click)="toggleModal(todo, 'addPhotoModal')"/>
    <img class="todoAction tooltip" md-tooltip="Location" tooltip-position="below"
         src="../../assets/img/location.svg"
         (click)="toggleModal(todo, 'addDescriptionModal')"/>
    <img class="todoAction tooltip" md-tooltip="Remove" tooltip-position="below"
         src="../../assets/img/remove.svg" (click)="removeTodo(todo)"/>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="todoDetails"> <!-- *ngIf="todo.showDetails" -->
  <div class="todoDetailsDescription">
      <textarea placeholder="Add Description..." class="descriptionTextArea" [(ngModel)]="todo.description"
                (keyup.enter)="updateDescription(todo)">
      </textarea>
  </div>
  <div *ngIf="todo.photoUrl" class="todoDetailsPhoto">
    <img src="{{todo.photoUrl}}"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

```css
    .todoDetails {
        z-index: -1 !important;
    }

    .todoDetailsDescription {
        width: 80%;
        height: 85px;
        margin: 4% auto;
        text-align: center;
        z-index: -1 !important;
    }

    .todoDescription textarea {
        font-size: 1em;
        margin: 1% 3%;
        min-width: 90%;
        max-width: 90%;
        padding: 1%;
        min-height: 65px;
        max-height: 65px;
        border: none;
        background: #f2f2f2;
        z-index: -1 !important;
    }

    .todoActions {
        float: right;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        width: 210px;
        z-index: 10000 !important;
    }

    .todoAction {
        display: none;
        width: 30px;
        height: 30px;
        cursor: pointer;
        margin: 10px;
        transition: color 0.2s ease-out;
        z-index: 10000 !important;
    }
```

**Screencapture**

[image]

So, as you can see, the img tags in the `todoActions` div that are assigned tooltips show behind the `todoDetails` div. How can I can my tooltips to show in front of the todoDetails/todoDescription divs?

Comment: Here is the link for my answer. it works: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72400731/16365448

Answer (score 1):

z-index is relative to sibling elements, so, giving a high z-index to .todoActions won't help you if its parent container (.view) is behind .todoDetails.

Without viewing the full code working, can't say 100%, but I think that the following rules will work:

```css
.view {
  position:relative; z-index:1;
}
.todoDetails {
  position:relative; 
  z-index:-1 !important;
}
```

Comment: Sadly, that did not work. The tooltips are still showing behind the todoDetails div.

Comment: anything in view should be over anything in todoDetails with those rules, so first, check if they are being overriden by some other css; if that´s not the case, the tooltip may be created in some weird place, but that´s probably not the case, since it probably has by default a high z-index. Probably view has position or zIndex specified in a different css, or something like that.