# matTooltipClass not applying css

Tags: css, angular, angular-material2

I am attempting to apply some css changes to `mat-tooltip` from angular material 2 and found in the documentation a `matTooltipClass` that can then be selected in the css file to make changes. However, I am not able to get it working.

component.html :

```
  <mat-cell 
    *matCellDef="let productInfo" 
    matTooltip="{{productInfo.description}}"
    matTooltipClass="tooltip">
     {{ productInfo.description}}
  </mat-cell>
```

component.scss:

```
.tooltip {
background-color: red;
color: blue;
font-size: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 55, accepted):

You have to use `::ng-deep` to override default CSS for material elements:

```
::ng-deep .tooltip {
  background-color: red;
  color: blue;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

Comment: I've been struggling with this for hours. Thank you very much, @bugs

Comment: why does this only work with class name "tooltip"? when i change to "mytooltip" it doesn't work!

Comment: Make sure to use :host before ::ng-deep to prevent the class is being applied to other components.

Answer (score 11):

In addition to what was stated above,
Here are two methods that worked for me:
-in the Component.scss:

```
::ng-deep mat-tooltip-component{
    & .mat-tooltip{
        color: green; // your custom properties here.
    }
}
```

-Globally:

```
.mat-tooltip{ // making the font size on the mat-tooltip 1.5rem globally
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    &.exaggerated-tooltip{  // to modify the tooltip create a class like this
        font-size: 2.5rem;  // and use it like this: *matTooltipClass="exaggerated-tooltip"* in the
        color: red;         // component in which you are putting the tooltip
    }
}
```

Comment: The "globally" approach is the only way with Angular Material 7 which is working for me!

Answer (score 6):

In Angular 15 I solved this problem as follows:

Component HTML file:

```
<mat-cell 
  *matCellDef="let productInfo" 
  matTooltip="{{productInfo.description}}"
  matTooltipClass="myTooltip">
   {{ productInfo.description}}
</mat-cell>
```

Global CSS file:

```
.myTooltip {
  .mdc-tooltip__surface {
    max-width: 350px;
    padding: 5px;
  }
}
```

No need for `ViewEncapsulation.None` or `!important`, which could result in layout problems with the rest of your component and are to be avoided. Also, `::ng-deep` being deprecated, I would advise against using it.

Comment: This worked "kind-of" with Angular 16. For some properties the `!important` was still needed, though. And I definitely needed the `ViewEncapsulation.None`. There was no way to use it otherwise.

Answer (score 3):

A blog post by Siderite ([Styling Angular Material tooltips](https://siderite.dev/blog/styling-angular-material-tooltips.html/)) provided an answer that worked for me. I am paraphrasing from the most-relevant portion of his post and I am using the matTooltipClass="tooltip" scenario described in the Question above:

> [The .tooltip class definition] should either be in the global CSS
> file (so it applies to everything) or your component should declare
> encapsulation ViewEncapsulation.None.  [If the .tooltip class
> definition is in the global CSS file], then ensure the declaration of
> the class is specific enough: try this:
> mat-tooltip-component .mat-tooltip.tooltip {...}.

In my case, I had defined the .tooltip class in the global styles.scss file, and it wasn't working until I followed Siderite's suggestion and defined it like this:

```
mat-tooltip-component .mat-tooltip.tooltip {
    color: blue !important;
}
```

This approach is avoids using ::ng-deep as suggested in the accepted Answer.  Angular documentation states that approach is [deprecated](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#deprecated-deep--and-ng-deep).  I did find I needed to use !important, which some believe is bad style.

Comment: In my case it worked only when I removed the first part, like this:
.mat-tooltip.tooltip {
    color: blue !important;
}

Comment: Putting the style in the `styles.scss` file and using `!important` finally solved the problem. Don't know why I need to place the style only there - but it worx! :-)

Answer (score 1):

Angular material doc says matTooltipClass supports the same syntax as ngClass.
thus you might try [matTooltipclass]="'tooltip'"

```
<mat-cell 
   *matCellDef="let productInfo" 
   matTooltip="{{productInfo.description}}"
   [matTooltipclass]="'tooltip'">
   {{ productInfo.description}}
 </mat-cell>
```

Answer (score 1):

From the example provided in the website (https://material.angular.io/components/tooltip/examples):

```
import {Component, ViewEncapsulation} from '@angular/core';

/**
 * @title Tooltip that can have a custom class applied.
 */
@Component({
  selector: 'tooltip-custom-class-example',
  templateUrl: 'tooltip-custom-class-example.html',
  styleUrls: ['tooltip-custom-class-example.css'],
  // Need to remove view encapsulation so that the custom tooltip style defined in
  // `tooltip-custom-class-example.css` will not be scoped to this component's view.
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
})
export class TooltipCustomClassExample {}
```

If you stick that `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None` line there for your component where you want to use your custom tooltip class, it ought to work. It's how I fixed the issue on my end.

Comment: So in order to get custom styles on the tooltip, we have to disable styles for the other material components in the same component?

Answer (score 0):

Seeing that `::ng-deep` is depricated now, best seems to be to add `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,` in your component decorator under your `styleUrls` line

Just be careful that all your css classes will be global then, so make sure your classes in that component have unique names if you do not want to overwrite the classes in other components accidentally

Answer (score 0):

I found out there is a div element down the body with class="cdk-overlay-container". I considered its z-index. it was 1000 below the z-index of my modal. I made it the same as my modal's z-index, i.e. 1050. And it is working. I also had to put ::ng-deep before my class in CSS file.

```
::ng-deep .cdk-overlay-container {
  z-index: 1050;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In case your project prohibits to use: ::ng-deep, you can use

> encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None

in the TS file.

Answer (score 0):

In Angular 15, similarly to what @StackOverflowUser said, I managed to do it with this code in my styles.scss file:

```
mat-tooltip-component .mdc-tooltip__surface {
    background-color: mat.get-color-from-palette(themes.$palette-tooltip, 400) !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside `matTooltipclass` you have to use **`''`** for the custom class

For example `[matTooltipclass]="'customTooltip'"`

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it worked using this in the component.scss file:

```
::ng-deep .mdc-tooltip__surface {
    max-width: unset !important; 
}
```